# Split string by vector of numbers

Tags: r, stringr

I have strings of unequal length such as:

```
  x <- c("11333333444A", "3aaa0085hb", "&ffvyß")
```

I want to break the strings in `x` into substrings based on the numeric information stored in a vector `y`:

```
  y <- c(2, 8, 11, 12)
```

to obtain the first `2` characters, then the following characters up until position `8` character, then up until position `11` character, and finally up until `12`:

```
 11, 333333, 444, A
 3a, aa0085, hb
 &f, fvyß
```

I've tried to use `str_locate_all`, `str_which`, and others from `stringr` but couod not figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With split positions given, an easier option is `separate` where the `sep` can take index of vectors as splitting delimiter

```
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(x) %>%
   separate(x, into = str_c('col', seq_along(y)), sep = y)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  col1  col2   col3  col4 
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 11    333333 "444" "A"  
2 3a    aa0085 "hb"  ""   
3 &f    fvyß   ""    ""
```

---

Or use `base R` with `read.fwf` and specify the `widths` by taking the `diff`erence of position index

```
read.fwf(textConnection(x), widths = c(y[1], diff(y)))
  V1     V2   V3   V4
1 11 333333  444    A
2 3a aa0085   hb <NA>
3 &f   fvyß <NA> <NA>
```